# ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled when getting GetColorFromHexa in Wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am getting ArgumentOutOfRangeException ,when i trying to get the color from hexavalues.

```
   public static SolidColorBrush GetColorFromHexa(string hexaColor)
    {
        return new SolidColorBrush(
            Color.FromArgb(
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(1, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(3, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(5, 2), 16),
                Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(7, 2), 16)
            )
        );
    }


  SolidColorBrush brush = GetColorFromHexa("#ADD8E6");
  border.Background = brush;
```

Am i missing anything that could be the reason of this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your parameter #ADD8E6 lacks one of the color components. AD D8 E6 are just three components, while ARGB needs four. Where is the fourth?
So the exception is thrown on line Convert.ToByte(hexaColor.Substring(7, 2), 16).

Answer (score 1):

`ArgumentOutOfRangeException -

startIndex plus length indicates a position not within this instance.`

`-or-`

`startIndex or length is less than zero`
-msdn

so this what caused your problem, in other words the values (the last one is 7,2) are out of range.

for some examples that might help you with [MSDN String.Substring Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs.aspx)

hope it helped, wish you good luck.